# Почему на разных url один .html?

Tags: python, django

Пытаюсь сделать в django переход между домашней страницей и другой. Вот urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = 'learning_logs'

urlpatterns = [
    #Домашняя страница
    url('', views.index, name='index'),
    #Вывод всех тем
    url('topics', views.topics, name='topics'),
]
```

Вот функция вывода страницы в views.py:

```
def topics(request):
    """Выводит список тем."""
    topics = Topic.objects.order_by('date_added')
    context = {'topics': topics}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/topics.html', context)
```

topics.html не показываю, потому что он почему-то ни на что не влияет. В этом и заключается моя проблема. http://localhost:8000/topics и http://localhost:8000/ выводят одну и ту же страницу index.html. Прочитал много руководств по созданию страниц: везде то же самое - внести url, функцию в views.py, сделать файл .html. Не могу понять, что я делаю не так, и почему /topics выводит index.html.

Comment: Урлы парсятся по порядку. Шаблон '' стоит первым, и он удовлетворяет условию при вводе адреса /topics

Answer (score 4, accepted):

При использовании функции `url` джанго использует регулярное выражение чтобы распознавать куда пользователь направляется.
И на вопрос твой "Почему при переходе на другой URL отсылается на один и тот же контроллер (view)", то на это ответил Александр выше в комментариях:

> Урлы парсятся по порядку. Шаблон `''` стоит первым, и он **удовлетворяет** условию при вводе адреса */topics*

Ты в своем коде написал:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    url('', views.index)
    url('topics', views.topics)
]
```

Так как я как написал выше что `url` использует регулярное выражение, то первое выражение `''` будет всегда с любой строкой возвращать True, и перенаправляться на `views.index`, а чтобы этого избежать нужно уточнить именно что пустой `url`, или же какой нибудь другой.
А это делается вот так:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    # Знак `^` означает начало строки, а знак `$` конец строки.
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^topics/$', views.topics, name='topics'),
]
```

А еще с приходом Django версии 2.0, добавили новую функцию `path`, которая упрощает написание url-ов.
И зная это, если ты используешь Django версии 2 или выше, то можно написать используя функцию `path`, вот так:

```
from django.urls import path

...

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('topics/', views.topics, name='topics'),
]
```